# Can't limit posts_per_page in loop

Tags: loop

I have a loop that cycles through every tag and displays 10 posts from each. This works, but I want to set it to only show 20 posts on each page overall i.e. page 1 shows tag 1, tag 2, then page 2 shows tag 3, tag 4 etc

I'm not sure how to do this. Do I need to put the foreach loop in another array and define posts_per_page in the new array? Or does it maybe require setting up a function with pre_get_posts?

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$car_group_terms = get_terms( 'post_tag' );

foreach ( $car_group_terms as $car_group_term ) {
            $car_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'car_listing',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $car_group_term->slug ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ) );

 while ($car_group_query->have_posts() ) : $car_group_query->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'content', 'car_listing' ); 
    }
    endwhile; 
    }
```

Comment: You'd be much better off making whatever you're using tags for into a custom field. Then you can sort by `meta_value`, making this *considerably* easier. As it is you're going to have to do some crazy nonsense in tracking and caching how far into each term each page of the query was, or modifying the SQL to add a custom join for sorting.

Comment: I have the tags part working though. It shows 10 posts from each tag like it should. I don't need to sort anything. I just want to limit each page to 20 posts.

Comment: You have it working because you're not using pagination and aren't trying to paginate with a potentially variable number of posts per tag. Your method breaks down entirely if you try to do that, which is what I"m telling you.